# C# acces database select with parameter

Tags: c#, sql

Hi i have problem with execute Query with Parameter in access database:

```
OleDbConnection cnn;
OleDbCommand cmdselect2;
string sqlselect2 = null;
string baza = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + @"L:\Windykacja\Sdro\Projekt\projekt.accdb";
connetionString = baza;
sqlselect2 = "SELECT count(POS_Pesel_regon) as Suma FROM POS WHERE POS_Pesel_regon = @PR";
cnn = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
cnn.Open();
cmdselect2 = new OleDbCommand(sqlselect2, cnn);
Int32 PR1 = Convert.ToInt32(cmdselect2.ExecuteScalar());
cmdselect2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PR", textBox6.Text);
cmdselect2.Dispose();
cnn.Close();
```

It's say that my paramter is missing

In insert it works perfectly :)

will be thankfull for any sugestions.

cheers

Comment: Add parameter before you execute command...

Answer (score 2):

Because you try to execute your command *before* you add your parameter. Change those lines

```
Int32 PR1 = Convert.ToInt32(cmdselect2.ExecuteScalar());
cmdselect2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PR", textBox6.Text);
```

to

```
cmdselect2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PR", textBox6.Text);
Int32 PR1 = Convert.ToInt32(cmdselect2.ExecuteScalar());
```

A few things more;

- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.
- Don't use `AddWithValue` as much as you can. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specify your parameter type and it's size.

```
using(var cnn = new OleDbConnection(connetionString))
using(var cmdselect2 = cnn.CreateCommand())
{
   cmdselect2.CommandText = @"SELECT count(POS_Pesel_regon) as Suma FROM POS 
                              WHERE POS_Pesel_regon = @PR";
   cmdselect2.Parameters.Add("@PR", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox6.Text;
   // I assumed your column type as VarChar
   cnn.Open();
   int PR1 = (int)cmdselect2.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: omg stupid me :) thanks You very much for help